# multi variables in subprocess.Popen with %dict()

Tags: python, variables, awk, popen

I have lots of images to optimize and sort all of the input names and output names in a csv file. previously, I use AWK to to such kind of work, but now I prefer to switch to python with .Popen method.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
cmdc2d='c2d %(inname)s -clip 1% 99% -type short -stretch 1% 99% 0 255 -o %(outname)s'
argscmd=shlex.split(cmdc2d)
subprocess.Popen(argscmd%dict(inname='test1.png',outname='test1-2.png'))
```

The output gave me a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'dict'
```

How could I pass all of those variables into the Ponpen []?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.  First, you need to perform the interpolation before splitting the string. Because you split the command string before the interpolation, the first operand to `%` in

```
argscmd%dict(inname='test1.png',outname='test1-2.png')
```

is a list, and `%` isn't a defined operation for a list and a dict.  You need the first operand to `%` to be a string.  Try something like:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
cmdc2d='c2d %(inname)s -clip 1% 99% -type short -stretch 1% 99% 0 255 -o %(outname)s'
argscmd=shlex.split(cmdc2d % dict(inname='test1.png',outname='test1-2.png'))
subprocess.Popen(argscmd)
```

Second, you need to escape the `%` symbols that are intended to be literal `%`s.  You'll want this:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
cmdc2d='c2d %(inname)s -clip 1%% 99%% -type short -stretch 1%% 99%% 0 255 -o %(outname)s'
argscmd=shlex.split(cmdc2d % dict(inname='test1.png',outname='test1-2.png'))
subprocess.Popen(argscmd)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works well. then I am going to take csv into the script.

Comment: @user3817800: `shlex.split()` breaks here if `inname` or `outname` contain space. You could [create the list directly instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25163739/4279)

Answer (score 0):

I would change @Alp answer to:

`subprocess.Popen(argscmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)`

This will allow you to close the Popen and also read inputs.
`os.setsid` is more like `exec` and `fork` in `C`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.setsid

Comment: since I start to read Popen(), almost every one said shell=True is insecure. I hesitate to use it for this moment...sorry

Comment: It is wrong. Don't use a list argument (`argscmd`) and `shell=True` together.  String argument should be used with `shell=True` in most cases instead of a list. Though I see no indication that `shell=True` is necessary in OPs case.

Answer (score 0):

To allow a space (or other special characters) in `inname`, `outname` filenames, construct the command as a list from the very beginning:

```
cmd = ['c2d', inname]
cmd += '-clip 1% 99% -type short -stretch 1% 99% 0 255 -o'.split()
cmd += [outname]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
...
```